# Equation number with an apostrophe

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath, align

I am writing two equations in an `align` environment:

```
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=z^2, \\
x^2=7,
\end{align}
```

I would like the first equation to be labelled with e.g. (1.1) and the second equation to be labelled (1.1'), rather than (1.2).

Is this possible to automate? Do I need to use a hack to manually place the equation number after my second equation? e.g.

```
\newcommand{\hack}{\hfill({\eqnum}')} % Sketch - I don't know what command to use.
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2=z^2, \\\nonumber
x^2=7,\hack
\end{align}
```

If so, what command can I use to get the equation number? i.e. what should my command `\hack` be?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Don't you mean a *prime* rather than an *apostrophe*?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not that familiar with the difference.

Comment: +1 for the question, but also for your nickname: I'm a fan of John Ford. ;-)

Comment: @egreg, I had to do a bit of searching to get that reference. I wasn't familiar with "The Isle of Innisfree", only with "The Lake Isle of Innisfree".

Comment: @TRiG “The quiet man” is one of John Ford's many masterpieces.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend using the `\tag` macro to directly insert the equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\begin{align}
 z^2&= x^2 + y^2     \\
 z^2 &=  x^2 + y^2  \tag{\theequation'}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As per @barbarabeeton 's answer, the `'` should be `\prime` as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}

\section{Section A}

\begin{align}
 z^2&= x^2 + y^2     \\
 z^2 &=  x^2 + y^2  \tag{\theequation${}^\prime$}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
 z^2= x^2 + y^2     
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Incidentally, the `\theequation` is the way to access directly the formatted `equation` counter. This works with any counter you're using, `\the<counter_name>` will call the formatted counter.  This is the reason `\theequation` resulted in `1.1` and not just `1`, which is the value of the counter `equation`.

Answer (score 17):

a method that will allow both equation numbers to be referenced outside the `align`
uses labels and `\ref`:

```
\begin{align}
 x^2+y^2=z^2, \label{firsteq}\\
 x^2=7, \tag{\ref*{firsteq}'} \label{primeq}
\end{align}
```

the job needs to be run three times to resolve the numbers.

the `*` on `\ref*` in the `\tag{...}` will prevent the equation number in the display
from being treated as a link.  however, the label for the number with the prime can still be referenced in text by `\eqref`, and that *will* be linked.

(not part of the answer, but a suggestion: prime is more usual than an apostrophe;
the apostrophe in this context will automatically be set as a prime.)

Comment: That could be helpful also, but how can I stop `\ref` being hyperlinked at that label if I use `hyperref`, which is not desired?

Comment: using `\ref*` for the reference in the `\tag{...}` will prevent the number on the equation itself from being made into a link.  the label for the "derivative" number will still be able to be linked from a reference in text.  i presume that's what you want.  (i'm adding this to the answer.)