# Special treatment of equation numbers i.e. \overline or \widehat

Tags: equations

Is there a way to make the equation numbers with an over line or over hat?  Can this be done for just a couple equations?

Comment: would you consider using a prime instead of a diacritic?  if so, then this may be helpful:  [Equation number with an apostrophe](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132408/579)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite easy using `\tag`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}

\begin{document}

We can even refer to equation~\eqref{ovl87} below:
\begin{multline}\label{ovl87}
\dfrac{B_1(\ovl{Q}_1, L)}{\sqrt{a}}  +
    n(r_1)\ovl{A}_7 + n(r_2) \ovl{A}_2(\ovl{A}_1, L) = \\
\dfrac{1}{2}
\left\{\sqrt{t_s^5 G_s^2 + 4 t_s G_s
    \left(\dfrac{4\pi^2D_s}{L^2} + F_\rho
    \right)}%end sqrt
                -t_sG_s
\right\}
\tag{$\ovl{87}$}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possibly better example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{equation}{86}% in order the next equation has number 87

Here we have an equation
\begin{multline}\label{main}
\dfrac{1}{2}
\left\{\sqrt{t_s^5 G_s^2 + 4 t_s G_s
    \left(\dfrac{4\pi^2D_s}{L^2} + F_\rho
    \right)}%end sqrt
                -t_sG_s
\right\}= \\
\dfrac{B_1(\ovl{Q}_1, L)}{\sqrt{a}}  +
    n(r_1)\ovl{A}_7 + n(r_2) \ovl{A}_2(\ovl{A}_1, L)
\end{multline}
that we can also write in the alternative form
\begin{multline}\label{mainovl}
\dfrac{B_1(\ovl{Q}_1, L)}{\sqrt{a}}  +
    n(r_1)\ovl{A}_7 + n(r_2) \ovl{A}_2(\ovl{A}_1, L) = \\
\dfrac{1}{2}
\left\{\sqrt{t_s^5 G_s^2 + 4 t_s G_s
    \left(\dfrac{4\pi^2D_s}{L^2} + F_\rho
    \right)}%end sqrt
                -t_sG_s
\right\}
\tag{$\ovl{\ref{main}}$}
\end{multline}
and we can refer to the alternate equation~\eqref{mainovl}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My 'dummied' in version was causing some formatting issues.  I have subsequently used your first suggestion and it works.  It is curious that there isn't the use of $ or $$ to bookend the equation.  Why does it 'work' this way?

Comment: @TommyK Look in the `.aux` file for the `\newlabel` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I love it when I can answer my own question.  It is kind of like losing something then accusing someone of stealing it, i.e. "Alright who stole my...", then voila! it turns up.

```
$%ovl87
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{B_1(\ovl{Q}_1, L)}{\sqrt{a}}  +
    n(r_1)\ovl{A}_7 & + n(r_2) \ovl{A}_2(\ovl{A}_1, L) = \\
& \dfrac{1}{2}
\left\{\sqrt{t_s^5 G_s^2 + 4 t_s G_s
    \left(\dfrac{4\pi^2D_s}{L^2} + F_\rho
    \right)}%end sqrt
                -t_sG_s
\right\}    
\end{aligned}
$
\hfill ($\ovl{87}$)
```

I have redefined `\ovl` to replace `\overline` in my preamble.

I decided for the sporadic use of the 'diacritic', I just 'dummied' the 'equation number' at the end of the line.  While it is not a real equation number, it does have the look and feel of an equation number.  This has the effect of placing the `\overline{87}` in line with the space between the two lines of the equation, making it look like a bona fide equation number.  This does not work with centered i.e. using `$$` instead of `$` as equation bookends.

Although, it might be advantageous to be able to define a diacritic for a string of equation numbers, as the need arises.

Comment: This may suit *your* needs, but it surely can be improved upon to serve a wider audience.

Comment: Yes, I hope that more will weigh in. While it does suite my current needs, I/we may need a less 'dummied' version later.

Comment: I've found out, quite by accident, that the \label at the beginning of the equation seems to be unnecessary.  Simply adding the \tag.... at the end, with all the modifiers, overline and a prime, in my case, seems to be sufficient.   Am I missing something?  Why the \label at the beginning?

Comment: The `\label` allows you to use `\ref` elsewhere in the document. Therefore, you only need to change the equation `\tag` once, and all `\ref`s to that instance will change accordingly. If you label things manually in the equation *and* in the text, then you'll have to change it twice whenever corrections are made. It's less prone to error when you only have to do things once.