# Equation number primed

Tags: equations, labels

Many times in mathematics one has an assumption (call it Assumption A) that has an interesting variant (call it Assumption A').  I often see in textbooks Assumption A will be written with an equation number like (I) while Assumption A' will get the number (I') to emphasize that it is a variant of (I).  Is there a way to do this in Latex without blowing up the automatic equation numbering?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Could you add an image how it should look like (see below the "edit" button). Could you provide some code?

Comment: You can use `\newtagform` that comes with the `mathtools` package.

Comment: see this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132401/equation-number-with-an-apostrophe

Comment: Load the `amsmath` package and use `\tag{A}` for assumption A and `\tag{A'}` for assumption A'. This method doesn't "blow up [LaTeX's] automatic equation numbering".