# Equation numbering with primes

Tags: equations, numbering

I searched stackexchange for a question like mine. There are a small number of similar ones, but none exactly like it. Or I didn't search correctly. My quest is this. I want to number an alternate equation with a prime. However, there are intervening equations. Note that equation 3 comes between equation 2 and equation 2'. I don't want to hardwire equation numbers because equation (1) may become equation (2) due a future edit and all the numbers would need to change.

```
    a = 1             (1)
    b = 2             (2)
    c = a + b = 3     (3)
    or alternatively,
    b = 3             (2')
    c = a + b = 4     (3')
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you label the equations you want to "prime", you can use those labels to derive the numbers of the "primed" equations.  I think there's already a question that shows how to do it, but don't have time to search for it.

Comment: Thank you, Barbara, for looking at this. Indeed all of my equations are labeled. What you say sounds like the solution I am looking for. I will search for it in Stackexchange as well as the wider web.

Comment: Some useful information here: [Equation number with an apostrophe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One relatively simple way is just to use the `\tag` command to set the number by using `\ref` to refer back to the original equation number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   a &= 1 \label{a}\\
   b &= 2 \label{b}\\
   c &= a + b = 3 \label{c}
\end{align}
or alternatively,
\begin{align}
    b &= 3 \tag{\ref{b}$'$}\label{bprime}\\
    c &= a + b = 4 \tag{\ref{c}$'$}\label{cprime}
\end{align}

Do you prefer \eqref{c} or \eqref{cprime}?
\end{document}
```

[image: tags and refs]

This may require multiple compilations to sync up the numbers.

Comment: Thank you frabjous, you are indeed frabjous. I have implemented this and it worked.

Comment: I'm sorry frabjous, I tried to uptick your answer but I was told I don't have enough reputation to do it.